# Is there an equivalent to range(arrayname) in c# like there is in python?

Tags: python, c#, loops

I have recently started working in C# and have come from a coding background in python. In python there is a way to loop through an array and set variable i to the number in the range
`for i in range(numbers)`
This would loop through the array setting i to the index in the array/list. Is there an equivalent in c# or do you have to use a counter to increment each time?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<limit; i++) ?

Comment: FWIW your understanding of the Python code is a bit off. `for i in range(x)` will only work if `x` is an integer, not an array/list/anything else. Are you thinking about `enumerate` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace Yeah I just wrote it out quickly and couldn't get the word if you know what I mean, but that's for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = 0;
}
```

If you want it the python way then the equivalent for Python's `range(...)` in C# is [`Enumerable.Range(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-5.0)

Then you can use the enumerable in a `foreach` loop.

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.Length);
foreach (var i in range)
{
    myArray[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement):

```cs
foreach (int i in numbers)
{
    // Do something with i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `foreach` to array and lists, but for numbers use this:

```cs
for (int = /* start */; i < /* end, exclusive */; i++)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who enjoy using linq expressions and don't have too much logic to fit inside the `for` loop, you can also use this approach:

```
Enumerable
    .Range(0, 10)
    .Where(x => IsEven(x))
    .Select(x => DoSomethingWithEvenElement(x));
```

**Description**:

This first creates a range, then filters elements out by passing them to:

`bool IsEven(int x)`

and then iterates the remaining values using `Select` which will pass each element to:

`TReturn DoSomethingWithEvenElement(int x)`